# laravel cashier invoicePrice() doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-8, laravel-cashier

I'm trying to use laravel cashier with stripe to generate invoice and charge users immediately but it doesn't work. i'm taking reference from the sample code snippet in the laravel-8 documentation to do this.

```
$user->invoicePrice('price_tshirt', 5, [
    'discounts' => [
        ['coupon' => 'SUMMER21SALE']
    ],
], [
    'default_tax_rates' => ['txr_id'],
]);
```

I created a product in my stripe dashboard and replaced 'price_tshirt' with the price ID of the product. the final code looks like this

```
if(!$user->hasPaymentMethod()){
    $user->addPaymentMethod($paymentMethod); //$paymentMethod method was genearated
}

$user->invoicePrice('price_xxxxxxx', 1, [], [
    'description' => 'this is a dummy description',
    'currency' => 'usd',
    'receipt_email' => 'john@doe.com'
]);
```

After running the code nothing happened, i looked at my stripe dashboard, i saw nothing. my goal is to charge users and generate invoice for them so that i can access those invoices later on in my application by doing something like this `$user->invoices()`

NOTE:
i was previously using `$user->charge(100, $paymentMethod);` which works perfectly but doesn't generate any invoice, then i decided to change and use `$user->invoiceFor()` method, this method only generated an invoice but the user wasn't charged. I decided to change again and use `$user->invoicePrice()` but this method didn't do anything at all. It is required that i let users manage their invoices after payment but i cannot find a method that can help me do that (generate invoice and charge). I don't know what i'm doing wrong, please help.

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/billing#charge-with-invoice) what you're doing should work.  When that code runs are you seeing any [Stripe API requests in the Stripe Dashboard](https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs)?  Are there any warnings or errors in your server logs?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? When I used $user->invoiceFor('one tiem charge','500); I got Nothing to invoice for customer

Comment: I found the problem, stripe docs say: pending_invoice_items_behavior
optional
How to handle pending invoice items on invoice creation. One of include or exclude. include will include any pending invoice items, and will create an empty draft invoice if no pending invoice items exist. exclude will always create an empty invoice draft regardless if there are pending invoice items or not. Defaults to exclude if the parameter is omitted.", Laravel is using include_and_require

Comment: Thanks @TDawg for your comment. So what you are saying in essence is to create an invoice line item first before using `$user->invoiceFor()` and that will create an invoice and charge the user afterwards, right?

Comment: i thought the laravel `invoiceFor()` method creates an invoice item behind the hood, creates an invoice, and then pays the invoice immediately, (as per their documentation). why do i need a seperate call of my own to create an invoice item?

Comment: Actually, after further research, I found the problem was on my side for another reason. It seemed I had a pending subscription invoice in EUR and my invoiceFor was USD. When I edited both to be same currency it worked as expected. Given that, I did test changing cashing to include and it worked no matter what currency, but I think that would have broken something else, so I restored it. Sorry, I suppose my case doesn't help you, it was a bit niche.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the issue is laravel using a "pending_invoice_items_behavior" of "include_and_require" which has been disabled by Stripe. So items are getting excluded by default.

https://mobile.twitter.com/cjav_dev/status/1554922729081516033

I tried including a new parameter like this.

```
$user->invoicePrice('price_XXXXXXXXXXXXXX', 5, [], [
    'pending_invoice_items_behavior' => 'include',
]);
```

I also however experienced the currency error, as my user had previously charged in CAD when I was trying a product in USD (Huge thanks to whoever posted that!!).

But when I created a new user instead of customer with a preexisting currency, it worked.